# How do update a specific field in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a data set which is

```
var JobSchema = Schema({
  candidates: [{
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    status: { type: String, default: 'In Progress' },
  }]
});
```

I want to find a specific `job's _id` and update a specific candidates' field such as `{ _id: 123, user: 12345, status: "In Progress" }`

The url for this operation is ---> `localhost:3000/apply/:job_id/user_id`

For example

Let say that this is the current saved data in job mongodb

```
  { 
   "_id" : 123, ---> job_id

   "candidates" : 
     [{ 
        "_id" : 234 , 
        "user": 345 , --> user_id
        "status" : "In Progress" 
     }, 

       { 
        "_id" : 345 , 
        "user": 678 , --> user_id
        "status" : "In Progress" 
      }]
    "__v" : 0 
  }
```

How do i update only a specific field let say `status` field that belong to a certain candidates' `_id` in mongodb, Here's my attempt

```
          Job.update(
                    {
                        _id: req.params.job_id,
                    },
                    {
                        $set: {'candidates.$.status': 'Accepted'} ,
                    }, function(err, count) {
                        if (err) return next(err);
                        callback(err, count);
                    });
```

I will get this error If I use the above operation.

MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: candidates.$.status

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) is the solution:

```
Job.update(
    { 
        _id: found._id, 
        'candidates.user': req.params.user_id
    },
    {
        $set: { 'candidates.$.status': 'Accepted'} },
    }, function(err, count) {
           if (err) return next(err);
           callback(err, count);
});
```