# How to update a nested object in using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Let say the current data on a given `User` is

```
{
            accountType:12,
            address:{
                address1:"uk1"
            },
            shareDealing:{
                providers:{
                    uk:{
                        accountProviderId:"12",
                        accountProviderName: "as",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I want to insert the following data changing all fields except that I am not including the `shareDealing.providers.uk.accountProviderName` because it hasn't changed and i expect that one to remain on the User's document

So my data to update would be

```
user = {
            accountType:22,
            address:{
                address1:"aaaaaa"
            },
            shareDealing:{
                providers:{
                    uk:{
                        accountProviderId:"333333333333",
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

So I ran the following code

```
User.update(searchBy, user, {upsert:true}).then((data) =>{

            if(data === null) throw new AppError(400,"User Not Found",5);

            res.json({ message: 'User Updated', data: req.body });
            logger.debug("Saved Data : Using  "+ JSON.stringify(searchBy) +" record: "+ JSON.stringify (data));
        }).catch( (error) => {
            new Errorhandler( new AppError(400,error)).display(req,res);
        });
```

**My problem**

When I do the update the updated User's record doesn't have the `accountProviderName: "as"` as it think that the latest JSON should be the full User record.

Is there a way to update all changed fields but keeping the previous non-touched fields with just an update?

I know a workaround is using the following code but (maybe wishful thinking) I would prefer to validate and assign data to my User record outside my update function chain.

It feels overkill having to do 2 calls to the DB one to find and another to update

```
User.findById(searchBy).then((fetchedUser) => {
            if(fetchedUser === null) throw new AppError(400,"User Not Found",5);

            // In my ideal world i would prefer to validate and assign data outside this chain
            return functionThatValidatesAndAssignsDataToTheUser(fetchedUser,user);
        }).then((model) => {
            return model.save();
        }).then((updatedModel) => {
            res.json({
                msg: 'model updated',
                updatedModel
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });
```

Comment: If you want to keep others fields then use `$set` like `User.update(searchBy, {$set: user}, {upsert:true})` that will keep all your remaining fields

Comment: @ArifKhan that didn't work is still removing the field that is not set in the update statement from the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `$set` in update query.Refer to the below query it is tested and working properly modify it according to requirement

```
db.agreements.update({},{ $set:
  {
    "accountType":45,
    "address.address1":"india",
    "shareDealing.providers.uk.accountProviderId":984,
    }
```

})

Answer (score -1):

You should use `$set` for that inside your `Model.update`. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742316/how-do-update-a-specific-field-in-mongoose) link for an example if you need to, should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to add the `{'$set': user}` to my desired query and didn't work. can you provide and example where it would work. thanks